# How to generate an MST file for a WiX instance transform?

Tags: wix, orca

I have an installer built using WiX, using the InstanceTransforms tag. For example:

```
<InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
   <Instance Id="Install2" ProductCode="*" UpgradeCode="guid-goes-here" ProductName="Product" />
</InstanceTransforms>
```

I'd like to view the effects of the instance transform using Orca.

I imagine I need to generate an mst file to do this.

What steps do I need to take to get from my WiX source file to an mst file representing my instance transform?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do that in ORCA. I only know the workflow where you change something within ORCA and then create the transform out of your modifications, using `Transform` -> `Generate Transform`.

However if you have your base MSI and the transformed MSI, you could use one of the following scripts contained in the Windows SDK (normally located in `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Samples\sysmgmt\msi\scripts`:

- `WiGenXfm.vbs - generates a transform from two databases, or compares them`
- `WiDiffDb.vbs - lists the differences between two databases (CSCRIPT only)`